# How to create an android app that close on shake events?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, accelerometer, shake

I want to create an app that which get close whenever the device shakes. Can anyone explain how to do that?

I have an idea that it requires to create a service that runs in background, but I am struggling with actual coding and don't know how to do it.

Comment: i hope it works for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256541/android-shakesensor-service-for-shake-detection-in-application-background

Comment: thanks, it help me a lot